# using jess rules in android studio .... jess (read) operation how to read from edit text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jess

android app that using jess rules .... how to give the rule the input using edit text

```
(defrule genderrule
  ?k <- (Human (gender nil))
=> (printout t "please enter the gender : female|male ")
   (modify ?k (gender (read))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `EditText editText` as a global, `?*editText*`, from your Java program. Then, in CLP, follow the usual Jess syntax to call method `getText`.

```
(defglobal ?*editText*)
```

And in the rule:

```
(modify ?k (gender (call ?*editText* getText)))
```